# Store procs in a hash (lots of them)

Tags: ruby, performance, metaprogramming, block

I may be into a situation where I might potentially have hundreds or maybe thousands of blocks within a program, being indexed by a hash. I'm experimenting with metaprogramming and I'm wondering if this might increase the memory overhead too much (processing won't be a problem after the application loads, since they won't be constantly operating and I think this might still be faster than reading an xml file of epic proportions).

Basically, I have lots tiny programs I'm handling as data. How far can I go with blocks before this "data" needs to be managed the old-fashioned way, by some external source, like databases and xml files?

Comment: I'll suggest you to use a profiler to monitor the changes in behaviour with the increased number of objects.

Comment: curious about your problem if you can say..  this sounds interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Thousands" is not going to be a problem. Just do it.

When you get into millions, then you might have to reconsider.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then my worries are gone. Thanks for the quick answer.